# \AfterGroup sorcery and choking tex/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, grouping

In the following code, the line `\AfterGroup*` (from the`etextools` package) causes the `pdfLatex` compiler to 'choke', i.e it produces only this output and the process is stuck forever, consuming 13% of CPU:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/arul/AppData/Local/Temp/TE_temp_preview5132.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(C:\Users\arul\AppData\Local\Temp\TE_temp_preview5132.aux)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
```

And for the code, I want to be able to access different parts of an object by their id, globally, but since the macros are created within a group (and `pgfkeys` are confined to current group), I need to execute the `\pgfkeys` command in global scope, and thus the `\AfterGroups*` command (or do I need 2 `\AfterGroups*`, the other to escape the `newenvironment` confinement?)

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,bm,color,etextools}%
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
%
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%
\def\addobjectpart#1#2#3{%
  \pgfkeys{/instance/#1/ref name/.initial={a}, /instance/#1/ref color/.initial={b}}%
  \pgfkeys{/instance/#1/ref name={#2}, /instance/#1/ref color={#3}}%
}%
%
\newenvironment{myobject}[1] {
  \newcommand*{\addpart}[1][]{\object[##1]};%
  \def\object[##1]##2;{%
    \begingroup%
      \def\objid{1}%
      \def\name{bla}%
      \def\objcolor{black!50}%
      \AfterGroup*{\addobjectpart{\expandonce{\objid}}{\expandonce{\name}}{\expandonce{\objcolor}}}% <! HELL BREAKS LOOSE
    \endgroup%
  };%
}{};%
\begin{myobject}[BLAH]%
  \addpart[]{text ehm};%
\end{myobject}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

EDIT: Complete logfile after aborting the process: http://pastebin.com/BuwTt305

Comment: If you wish to use object, you can have a look to the `oo` module of PGF.

Comment: Thanks, the naming is kinda arbitrary though :)

Comment: Using `\color` is surely not a good idea, being it the main command for choosing colors. Also `etextools` is quite buggy; I'm not saying it has bugs in `\AfterGroup`, though. Can you make a selfcontained example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, please?

Comment: Codesample cleaned, problem persists :/

Comment: Updated with SSCCE (sorry for not providing one in the beginning, its my 3rd day with TeX in general:D)

Comment: Defining an environment inside a TikZ picture, which in turn defines a command that defines four commands is not what I'd call good programming style. ;-)

Comment: So your question is how do we define global keys? Is that about right such that you can avoid all this stuff?

Comment: @percusse that sounds about right, I already solved the problem, but why the whole TeX chokes on the code I posted is still a mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this is the final code that works, the key ingredient was the `\noexpand` inside the `objmacro` :

```
\xdef\objmacro{\noexpand\addobject {\objname}{\objcolor}}
\aftergroup\objmacro
```

My problem was that I started with `Pgf/Tikz` without knowing anything about the underlying technologies it was build upon. I think TeX is amazing! The package for typesetting computer instructions and pseudocode will soon land on CTAN.

[image: ArmV8 Instruction]

```
\begin{instruction}{85. LDR (register)}%
%
    \addpart[bits=5,register] {Rd};%    
    \addpart[bits=5,register] {Rn};%
    \addpart[bits=2] {0, 1};%
    \addpart[bits=1,opcode] {S};%
    \addpart[name=opc1,opcode,bits=3,name overlay=red!30] {option};%
    \addpart[bits=5,register] {Rm};%
    \addpart[bits=9] {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};%
    \addpart[name=size,bits=2,name overlay=orange!50] {x,1};%   
    %
    \newvariant[32-bit, node={size}, equals]{10};%
    %
    \newmnemonics[operand={<Wt>}, comma, open bracket, optional={<Xn|SP>}, comma, optional={<R>}, optional={<m>},
       open curly, variant={<extend>}, open curly, comma, inner variant={<amount>}, 
       close curly, close curly, close bracket]{LDR};
    %
    \newvariant[64-bit, node={size}, equals]{11};%
    %
    \newmnemonics[operand={<Xt>}, comma, open bracket, optional={<Xn|SP>}, comma, optional={<R>}, optional={<m>},
       open curly, variant={<extend>}, open curly, comma, inner variant={<amount>}, 
       close curly, close curly, close bracket]{LDR};
    %
%
\end{instruction}%
```